# script or exe to disable internet explorer in windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a script or a program to disable internet explorer in windows 7, silently if possible.

Can you help me? thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like a subject more suitable for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

disable-ie.bat:

```
@echo off
C:
cd "\Program Files\Internet Explorer"
if not exist IEXPLORE.EXE goto End
if exist IEXPLORE.EX_ del IEXPLORE.EX_
if not exist IEXPLORE.DIR md IEXPLORE.DIR
if not exist IEXPLORE.DIR goto End
attrib -r -h -s IEXPLORE.EXE
ren IEXPLORE.EXE IEXPLORE.EX_
if exist IEXPLORE.EXE goto End
ren IEXPLORE.DIR IEXPLORE.EXE
echo IE disabled.
echo If prompted, click "Cancel" then "Yes" on File Protection restore.
echo Run enable-ie.bat to allow IE to run again.
:End
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting an invalid proxy address in the registry

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v "ProxyEnable" /d 1 /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v "ProxyServer" /d 0.0.0.0:0000 /f
```